# failed to link /system/bin/sh CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been using the Android development tools in Eclipse to make a proof-of-concept app for my employer, to show them what our company can do with apps. I've got a long history of programming with and without IDEs; I've written several internal Java tools using Eclipse. However, I've never messed around under the hood of Eclipse or the ADT.

I was hammering away at the project this morning, and I changed one simple string in res/values/strings.xml. I didn't even change the length of the string, just changed two characters from "35" to "50". When I hit Run to see the changes, I got this cryptic message in the console output:

```
[2012-02-21 13:56:58 - CableCalc2] ------------------------------
[2012-02-21 13:56:58 - CableCalc2] Android Launch!
[2012-02-21 13:56:58 - CableCalc2] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-21 13:56:58 - CableCalc2] Performing com.rletech.cablecalc2.CableCalc2 activity launch
[2012-02-21 13:56:58 - CableCalc2] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'first_avd' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-21 13:56:58 - CableCalc2] WARNING: Unknown device API version!
[2012-02-21 13:56:58 - CableCalc2] Uploading CableCalc2.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-21 13:57:01 - CableCalc2] Installing CableCalc2.apk...
[2012-02-21 13:57:01 - CableCalc2] Success!
[2012-02-21 13:57:01 - CableCalc2] Starting activity com.rletech.cablecalc2.CableCalc2 on device emulator-5554
[2012-02-21 13:57:01 - CableCalc2] ActivityManager: link_image[1995]: failed to link /system/bin/sh
[2012-02-21 13:57:01 - CableCalc2] ActivityManager: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
[2012-02-21 13:57:01 - CableCalc2] ActivityManager:
```

... and I'm stuck there.  I tried some other projects that I know should work, because they've worked before, including the classic HelloAndroid project. All projects give me this same failure.

I didn't change anything in the code. It's like the ADT or Eclipse changed something for me and forgot to tell me about it. Any clue on how I can fix it?

**System details:**
Eclipse Indigo SR1 build ID 20110916-0149. Downloaded some time ago.
Android Development Toolkit version 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534. Downloaded on 6-Feb-2012.
ADB version is 1.0.29
Emulator platform 2.2 (API level 8)

**Update before posting:** I also have a platform for 4.0.3 (API level 15), and everything still works when I change the Run Configuration to 4.0.3. That's fine, but our customers don't run out and buy new Androids every month, so we need to run it and test it on API level 8. And like I said, it stopped working on API level 8, rather abruptly and not for a predictable reason.

As a proof of concept, this isn't looking terribly good. So once again, how do I fix it?

--
Regards
Ray

Comment: assuming you're running *nix, the script somewhere is trying to link to /system/bin/sh which is not found - is it there?  If so, do you have permission to link to it (or to create a link where the script is requesting?)

Comment: @Kevin, that's the goofy thing. I'm doing all of this in Windows XP. (Running XP because another one of my jobs is maintaining some FW on old Freescale processors.) I've got Cygwin on my machine, and I used it to go grepping around in the android-sdk/platforms directories, but I couldn't find anything that looked like /system/bin/sh.

Comment: I think you've got a whopper on your hands :( good luck

Comment: Thanks. I looked around some more on stackoverflow.com and elsewhere, for something that might be related. User @Caimen posted on "How to get an Android app running on API level 7 and 8?" on May 24 '11, that he had figured out that his 2.2 emulator was corrupt, and he simply deleted it and created a new one. Okay. I tried it; it works. If I can't solve the problem, then I guess a workaround will do. :)

Answer (score 1):

WAY late to the party here, but I've found that you can get this error when `/system/bin/linker` is deleted from your Android device.  (In my case, I was trying to update `linker` at runtime).  A missing `linker` seems to throw this error on *every* executable, not just `sh`.  In my case, I was able to restore `/system/bin/linker` with `adb push`, but the device still continued to have problems, and ultimately, completely re-flashing the OS was the only solution I found that worked.